# No importar base de datos con tidyverse

Tags: r

el paquete que estoy utilizando es tidyverse, estoy importando esta base de datos desde cvs pero sales este error

```
> arroz <- read_table(choose.files(), col_names = T, col_types = cols(
+   fecha = col_date("%d/%m/%y"),
+   precio = col_number()
+ ))
Warning message:
The following named parsers don't match the column names: fecha, precio
```

la fecha es dia-mes-año y la base de es esta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

La función [`read_table()`](https://rdrr.io/cran/readr/man/read_table.html) tiene un particular comportamiento, según se menciona en la documentación:

> **read_table()** is more strict, each line must be the same length, and
>   each field is in the same position in every line. It first finds empty
>   columns and then parses like a fixed width file.

Es decir, cada línea, la misma longitud (esto no es cierto en realidad) y cada columna en la misma posición (esto sí). Un archivo como este:

```
fecha precio
01—01—96 123
02—01—96 124
```

No funciona, pero si lo haría si las columnas estarían perfectamente alineadas:

```
fecha    precio
01—01—96 123
02—01—96 124
```

La opción, si no es posible reformatear el archivo, es usar [`read_table2()`](https://rdrr.io/cran/readr/man/read_table.html) que es más laxa en cuanto al formato y debería poder importar tu archivo sin inconvenientes:

> **read_table2()** is like **read.table()**, it allows any number of whitespace
>   characters between columns, and the lines can be of different lengths.

Comment: me sigue dando el mismo error

Comment: Entonces hay alguna fila que no respeta este formato, revisa aquellas filas dónde no se haya podido determina la fecha, por ejemplo `df[is.na(df$fecha), ]`